# XAML::Connecting many .cs file in main.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, controltemplate

I am making a progress bar through control template. I have defined control template in a file name `library.xaml` and handling its events in `library.cs` and in `main.xaml` I have defined progress bar and I want to change the width of progress but i cant access the rectangle from control template in `main.xaml.cs`.
Here are my all the file snapshot ..

`main.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="custom_template.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="1200">
    <Grid>
      <ProgressBar  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=my_progressbar_primary}"           Margin="385,176,307,122" Width="500"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`library.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="custom_template.library">
<Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="style_shadow_top">
    <Setter Property="Fill">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="#dddddd" Offset="0.25"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop Color="#F5F5F5" Offset="0.75"></GradientStop>
             </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="style_shadow_top_primary">
    <Setter Property="Fill">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="#76b9f4" Offset="0.25"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop Color="#428bca" Offset="0.75"></GradientStop>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style  x:Key="my_progressbar_primary">
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
   <Setter.Value>

    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
            <Rectangle x:Name="a" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20px"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"  Stroke="#ddd"  ClipToBounds="True" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Style="{StaticResource style_shadow_top}">
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle  Height="20" Width="100"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Style="{StaticResource style_shadow_top_primary}">
        </Rectangle>
       </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`library.cs`

```
namespace custom_template
 {
   partial class library
    {

      private void mouseenter_rect(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {

       ((Rectangle)sender).Width++;

   }

}
}
```

**Problem:** How can i access all the elements from library.xaml and library.cs in main.xaml.cs

Comment: I think that you need to create some dependency properties to make the members accessible in outside of the library.